# GtkScale slider's background-color property does not work properly

Tags: gtk

I have made a ui file using Glade.
It contains a `GtkWindow`, a `GtkScale` and a `GtkAdjustment`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Generated with glade 3.38.2 -->
<interface>
  <requires lib="gtk+" version="3.24"/>
  <!-- interface-css-provider-path ui.css -->
  <object class="GtkAdjustment" id="adj">
    <property name="upper">100</property>
    <property name="step-increment">1</property>
    <property name="page-increment">10</property>
  </object>
  <object class="GtkWindow">
    <property name="width-request">500</property>
    <property name="height-request">200</property>
    <property name="can-focus">False</property>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkScale">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can-focus">True</property>
        <property name="adjustment">adj</property>
        <property name="round-digits">1</property>
        <property name="draw-value">False</property>
      </object>
    </child>
  </object>
</interface>
```

I have some CSS to change the appearance of the `GtkScale`:

```
trough {
    background-color: #99b0c4;
    min-height: 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

highlight{
    background-color: #4e90cd;
    min-height: 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

slider {
    background: #09b32e;
    min-height: 30px;
    min-width: 30px;
    background-color: #f9b32e;
}
```

I was playing around with the background of the slider. I want it to be the color `#f9b32e`, but somehow it will not change to this color unless I set `background` to be something.

When I preview the code above, I get this:
[image]

But whenever I remove the line `background: #09b32e;` this is the preview:

[image]

The same goes for the property `background-image`. If I preview this without `background` but **with** `background-image` and `background-color`, it works as expected (`background-color` takes effect). Except there will be an image on the slider...

Is there something I am doing wrong, when I try to use `background-color` without any other background-properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed that using `background` as the background color (instead of `background-color`) works as expected.
I don't know why `background-color` does not work, but at least I get the behaviour I wanted.